# How many real solutions $(x,y)$ for $x + y^2 = y^3 $ and $y + x^2 = x^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I think the answer is that there are $3$ real solutions.

- When $x = y$
- When $x = -y$

If $x\neq y$ is there a real solution? If so, how do we find the real solutions?

Comment: Try subtracting one equation from the other and then factor out $x-y$.

Comment: i get $(x - y)(1 + (x +y)) = {(x-y)}^3 - 3xy(x-y)$ but then what am i supposed to do? for $x \neq y$ i can cancel out $(x-y)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtracting one equation from the other, we obtain $$(x-y)+\left(y^2-x^2\right)=\left(y^3-x^3\right)\Rightarrow$$ $$(x-y)\left(1+(x+y)+\left(x^2+xy+y^2\right)\right)=0\Rightarrow$$ $$(x-y)\left(\frac14 (1 + 2 x + y)^2+\frac1{12}(3y+1)^2+\frac23\right).$$ The second factor is strictly positive, so the only possibility is that $x=y$. In this case, our initial condition becomes $$x+x^2=x^3,$$ which gives the $\boxed{3}$ solutions $$(0,0),\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2, \frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right),\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2, \frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right).$$

Comment: so $x = -y$ not possible either?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter It is, but it just gives the solution $(0,0)$ once more. We can double check: if $x=-y$, our equations become $x+x^2+x^3=0$ and $x-x^2+x^3=0$. Subtracting them implies $2x^2=0$, or $x=0$, and therefore $y=0$ too.

Comment: can you explain why $$(x-y)\left(1+(x+y)+\left(x^2+xy+y^2\right)\right)=0$$ become $$(x-y)\left(\frac14 (1 + 2 x + y)^2+\frac1{12}(3y+1)^2+\frac23\right).$$

Comment: @Lifeforbetter This is highly non-trivial to find: I had to use WolframAlpha and a bit of cleverness to do so myself. However, to verify this, it suffices to expand $\frac14(1+2x+y)^2+\frac1{12}(3y+1)^2+\frac23$. Everything should work out.

Comment: why do you need to expand the expression into 2nd one, isnt the 1st expression already show that definite positive if $x \neq y$ ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter I do so to prove $1+(x+y)+\left(x^2+xy+y^2\right)>0$. There are other ways to do so, notably by taking the partial derivatives, but expressing it as the sum of positive terms was one way I really liked.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $y=x^3-x^2$ into the other equation gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
x(x^8-3x^7+3x^6-2x^5+2x^4-x^3-1)=0 \\
x(x^2-x-1)( x^6-2x^5 +2x^4 -2x^3 +2x^2-x+1) =0 \\
x(x^2-x-1) \left( (x^4+x^2)(x-1)^2+ \frac{1}{4} (2x-1)^2 + \frac{3}{4} \right) =0. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
So you are indeed correct: there are $3$ real solutions.